# Change in LIMIT clause while upgrading jooq from 3.14.6 to 3.17.5

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to upgrade JOOQ from 3.14.6 to 3.17.5. I am observing that generated SQL across two versions are different

Jooq 3.14.6

```
SELECT 
  public.payment.request_id 
FROM 
  payment 
WHERE 
  payment.status_expire_at < cast(
    '2007-12-03 10:15:30+00:00' as timestamp(6) with time zone
  )
) 
order by 
  public.payment.status_expire_at ASC LIMIT 10;
```

In Jooq 3.17.5

```
SELECT 
  public.payment.request_id 
FROM 
  payment 
WHERE 
  payment.status_expire_at < cast(
    '2007-12-03 10:15:30+00:00' as timestamp(6) with time zone
  )
) 
order by 
  public.payment.status_expire_at ASC FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Can someone let me know

1. If there are any settings in jooq codegen (version 3.17.5) which will allow me to have the generated SQL same as in 3.14.6?
2. Is there any documentation link which summarizes all changes in generated SQL across Jooq versions from 3.14.6 to 3.175?

DB - Postgres

Comment: The exact SQL statement is an implementation detail of the library - it can and will change. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, and asking for off-site resources like release notes or documents summarizing changes across versions are off-topic as well.

Comment: Also, the `FETCH` clause is part of the PostgreSQL syntax, so it is unclear what problem you're trying to solve, other than that apparently you don't like change(?).

Comment: `FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` will do exactly the same thing as `LIMIT 10` - what exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: "*Is there any documentation link which summarizes all changes*" - this is typically covered in the [release notes](https://www.jooq.org/notes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Older PostgreSQL version support

You might be using an older version of PostgreSQL that didn't support the standard SQL `FETCH` clause yet? Please refer to the [support matrix](https://www.jooq.org/download/support-matrix) to see which jOOQ version (and edition) supports which PostgreSQL version. The commercial editions still support a lot of old PostgreSQL versions.

#### Your specific questions:

> If there are any settings in jooq codegen (version 3.17.5) which will allow me to have the generated SQL same as in 3.14.6?

No, there's no configuration for this particular syntax, other than the `SQLDialect`, which is integration tested against every supported PostgreSQL version.

> Is there any documentation link which summarizes all changes in generated SQL across Jooq versions from 3.14.6 to 3.175?

Yes, the [release notes](https://www.jooq.org/notes) or the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues). This particular change was probably introduced in jOOQ 3.15 with PostgreSQL 13 support:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10645

In particular, the native PostgreSQL `FETCH FIRST .. WITH TIES` support probably triggered this change.

#### Possible solutions:

- You can stick with jOOQ 3.14.x, where the jOOQ Open Source Edition (assuming you're using that) did yet support PostgreSQL 13 and this syntax
- You can upgrade to a commercial jOOQ edition, which still supports PostgreSQL 12 and less
- You can upgrade PostgreSQL to something more recent
- You can patch the generated SQL string with a regex in an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/): Search `FETCH NEXT (\?|\d+) ROWS ONLY` and replace by `LIMIT $1`. Note that while it's `OFFSET .. FETCH`, it's `LIMIT .. OFFSET`, so if you want to use this approach, beware of having to invert the order of the bind values as well. This is more of a hack, of course, the other options are much better.

Comment: `FETCH FIRST` was introduced in Postgres 8.4 - it would be really bad if that version was still in production.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Probably not actually PostgreSQL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_synopsis.html

Comment: Well, if tuk is really using Redshift, the question should have been tagged with that, not with Postgres

Comment: I am using JOOQ open-source version which supports Postgres 14. Postgres version is older than 14 in a few of our services. So was trying to understand if there is a way I can get a list of all SQL changes (like the LIMIT one) and if there is a way I can generate a sql code compatible with a previous version of Jooq. As suggested I will upgrade the postgres to 14 in all services and then upgrade jooq to 17. Thanks Lukas and @a_horse_with_no_name for replying.